# IE8 Not working with script and html5

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer

A friend of mine does volunteer work for a website and came to me the other day with a problem.  Apparently a few of the users (who from the ones that have responded) who are running IE8 in particular, are not able to view the page layout properly.  This script is in the header of every page at the very top before the css.  It's looks from the screen shot he showed me that IE is ignoring the CSS and overlapping the sections of the website.  Any ideas on why?

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Thanks ahead of time for any help.

Comment: Tell them to get a real browser :-). Joking aside, it is very difficult to answer your question with such little information. Is the site publicly available to browse?

Comment: If they paste `http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js` into the address bar of their browser does it download the file?

Answer (score 0):

We will probably need to see the site to give you a good answer, but here are a few possible ideas to troubleshoot.

1. Do the users have JavaScript enabled? without it that script wont work at all. The only way to avoid this is to not use html5 which isn't a great option unless ie8 support is very important for the users of the site.
2. Are there any JS errors on the page? It could be preventing it from loading.
3. Try Downloading that js file and loading it locally instead of from google. Sometimes cross domain requests can cause problems. I've never had a problem with loading it from google, but you may want to try. Some browsers treat it differently. see Wikipedia: [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)
4. You also may want to make sure that file is the problem. Maybe there is some other ie weirdness going on. ie8 wont recognize html5 elements so it doesn't style them. if that's the layout problem you're getting then it probably is that file.

one other thing. Don't forget to use an html5 reset in your stylesheet to set the html5 elements in ie to 'display:block'. They may not work right without it.

**EDIT:**
Heres an example of what I mentioned in the comment.

In the HTML file:

```
<div class="container">
    <section id="left"><!-- sidebar --></section>
    <article><!--  content --></article>
</div>
```

In the stylesheet:

```
.container{
    position:relative;
}

section#left{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  I just heard back from my buddy.  The site is www.worldofhummingbirds.com.  The css is as follows:

Comment: header, section, article, footer { padding: 10px 20px 20px; margin: 10px; border: 1px solid #e7e2d7; background: #ffffff url(images/bg.png) repeat-x; border-radius: 8px; }  section#left { position: absolute; width: 200px; font-size: 1em; margin: 0px 0px 10px 10px; z-index: 25;}  article {margin-left: 270px; overflow: hidden; padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px;}

Comment: I see that in ie7 the sidebar(section tag) is sitting on top of the content area(article tag). Is this the problem you were seeing? I dont think that is an issue with the HTML5. The HTML5 tags seem to be working fine. Looks more like a compatibility issue.

Comment: The problem with the sidebar sitting on top of the content in ie7 is because the attribute 'position:absolute' is on the sidebar without a top/bottom and left/right attribute. If you wrap your content area (section#left and article) in a div and add the attribute 'position:relative' to that div, then add 'top:0' and 'left:0' to the sidebar it should fix the problem.

Comment: Thanks MPetty.  He said he changed some things around so hopefully it works better.  Unfortunately, I run IE8 and can't beta test it for him.  How does it look to you?

Comment: Just a heads up, if you have ie installed, you can open up the developer tools(F12) and select different page rendering methods from ie7 to the version of ie you have installed. This will allow you to test it in different versions of ie. I checked the site in ie7+ and it looks like its rendering correctly in all.